# php change logged admin as user and back

Tags: php

I have php application with admin and user access. What i want to do is this;

while logged in as admin, I need to click on a button and login as a user without login off from admin panel. Form the user control panel i want to be able to click for example "Back to Admin" button and login as admin. I need to remain loged all the time only to swap between user and admin control panel . I have my sessions set as folowing:

```
    Session::init();
        Session::set('role', $data['role']);
        Session::set('userid', $data['userid']);
        Session::set('language', $data['language']);
        Session::set('loggedIn', TRUE);

if ($data['role'] == "admin") {
          header('location: ' . URL . 'spadmincp');
        } elseif ($data['role'] == "owner") {
          header('location: ' . URL . 'dashboard');
        } elseif ($data['role'] == "default") {
          header('location: ' . URL . 'userservices');
        } elseif ($data['role'] == "reseller") {
          header('location: ' . URL . 'reseller');
        }
      } else {
        header('location:' . URL . 'login   ');
      }
```

I will appreciate any help

Thanks

Comment: Are you checking the login data at the top of the page? If not, then you only need a link to the right page.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.
On Admin Panel put the link to got to the user panel.

Eg.

```
<a href="Your user panel url">Go To User Panel</a>
```

And at user panel.

Check if it is admin and display the back to admin button.

```
 if($_SESSION['role']=='admin')
```

echo 'Back to admin';

also at user panel you may add. access to admin or user during security check.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you store an adminuserid in your session and use that at the admin pages and use the userid on the not-admin pages?

Answer (score 0):

try to put a last_role and last_userid variable in the session, when the admin change the user save his role/userid, give him the new ones, when he switch back clear the last ones, after he got back his own credintials.